# Is there a way to automatically delete files in the tmp folder?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, cron

Is there a way to automatically delete files with the thumb extension in the tmp folder when Ubuntu's capacity has exceeded 80 percent or one month later?

Should I use crontab? Or should I write crontab and shellscript at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you can just use the standard method of deleting files based on age, with a slight modification to reduce the threshold if the filesystem is too full.

The normal method for deleting all `*.thumb` files in `/tmp` over a certain age (about a month) is with a command like:

```
find /tmp -type f -name '*.thumb' -mtime +30 -delete
```

So, all you need to do is to reduce the threshold is to modify the `mtime` test under some circumstance. To do this based on how full the file system is could be done with something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Default to about a month.

thresh=30

# Get percentage used of /tmp, needs to match output of df, such as:
#  Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
#  tmp              1000000    280000    720000  28% /tmp

tmppct=$(df | awk '$6=="/tmp" { gsub("%", "", $5); print $5 }')

# Reduce threshold if tmp more than 80% full.

[[ ${tmppct} -gt 80 ]] && thresh=1

# Go and clean up, based on threshold.

find /tmp -type f -name '*.thumb' -mtime +${thresh} -delete
```

The only possibly tricky bit of that script is passing the output of `df` (based on format specified) through:

```
awk '$6=="/tmp" { gsub("%", "", $5); print $5 }'
```

This will simply:

- look for lines where the sixth field is `/tmp`;
- remove the trailing `%` from the fifth field; and
- finally output that (modified) fifth field to capture the percentage full.

Then just create a `crontab` entry that will run that script periodically.